# Insert new row if value present in column

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I need to check if a column value exists for a record, and if so insert a duplicate of that record, with one of the fields updated.

The fields for my IncCodes table are are chars:

```
IncomeCode,
Description,
Location,
CostCentre,
NewIncomeCode
```

I already have an SQL command which updates all of the IncomeCodes from the NewIncomeCode and clears the NewIncomeCode column where present:

```
UPDATE IncCodes 
SET IncomeCode = NewIncomeCode
   ,NewIncomeCode = ''
WHERE NewIncomeCode <> ''
  AND Location = Location1
```

However I need command which does the same thing except instead of updating the IncomeCode field, creates a duplicate record with the IncomeCode updated by the NewIncomeCode field. Something like this pseudo sql:

```
INSERT INTO IncCodes
VALUES (SELECT NewIncomeCode
              ,Description
              ,Location
              ,CostCentre
              ,NULL
        FROM IncCodes
        WHERE NewIncomeCode <> '')
```

Any advice much appreciated. I can see similar questions about insert based on criteria but nothing specifically what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS name(SQL Server/MySQL/Oracle). I would suggest to give some example data and expected output in your question.

Comment: Syntax error, instead do "INSERT INTO IncCodes SELECT..."

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and tips guys. I've tagged it Sybase SQL and marked the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO IncCodes
    (IncomeCode, Description, Location, CostCentre, NewIncomeCode)
SELECT
    NewIncomeCode, Description, Location, CostCentre, ''
FROM IncCodes
WHERE NewIncomeCode <> '' AND Location = Location1
;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO IncCodes (IncomeCode,Description,Location,CostCentre,NewIncomeCode)
SELECT NewIncomeCode
              ,Description
              ,Location
              ,CostCentre
              ,NULL
        FROM IncCodes
        WHERE NewIncomeCode <> ''
```

Never write an insert without specifying the columsn that is a SQL antipattern and can cause lots of data integrity problems.

Comment: The Null had to be a '' on this so I gave the answer to Vlad. Thanks though!